# Check which modules are observing an event

Tags: event-observer, products, magento-1

How can see if some extension is observing the `product_save_after` event?

The problem is that my "Special price From" field seem to be connected to the "New product from" field, if I put a Special price automatically the "New product from" field will be filled so I was wondering if there are something that I can check to see this kind of automatic connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using unix, run this

```
find . | xargs grep 'product_save_after' -sl
```

inside your app/code/local and app/code/community directory. This will return a list of occurrences and the filename. Then you will be able to check if there is any extension using that event.

Comment: mbalparda +vote  from me

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help, I can't access to my unix, I have just the access for my ftp and admin panel of my website, nothing more, I can do something in that way? Thank you again.

Comment: No, definitely not something automatic. Ask your host provider to run that for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I'll try, because honestly, for now, it's the only way to try to solve the problem that I have found, I hope to figure out something good or I don't know where other thing check! Doh.

Comment: The manual approach is to open each and every XML inside your modules folder and see if some of them are observing that event in particular, but it might take you a while if you have a lot of modules.

Comment: Ok, I'll do even this task, I'll put some music on in the meanwhile! eheh! Thank you again!

Comment: Hello, I tried with the unix but the command is not giving anything, like, it gives me always the new line command to write it again. Just to be sure, it's because didn't find anything or because I'm doing something wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Option 1, no results. The command is correct, but the event name is not an "official" event. Check that and run the command again.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the shell, you can upload the following PHP script in the document root:

```
<?php
$event = 'product_save_after';
echo '<h1>' . $event . '</h1>';

include 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app();

$observers = $app->getConfig()->getNode('global/events/' . $event);
echo '<h2>global observers</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
echo $observers ? htmlentities($observers->asNiceXml()) : 'none';
echo '</pre>';

$observers = $app->getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/events/' . $event);
echo '<h2>adminhtml observers</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
echo $observers ? htmlentities($observers->asNiceXml()) : 'none';
echo '</pre>';

$observers = $app->getConfig()->getNode('frontend/events/' . $event);
echo '<h2>frontend observers</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
echo $observers ? htmlentities($observers->asNiceXml()) : 'none';
echo '</pre>';
```

Then open it in the browser and you will see an excerpt of the merged config XML files. The `<class>` elements tell you, which modules the observers belong to. Change the first line `$event = 'product_save_after';` to look for a different event.

#### Example output

> [image: screenshot]

**If you are doing this on a production server, add password protection or remove the file immediately after usage!**